# Criterion for a factorial ratio to be integral

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, factorial

Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_K,b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_L$ be positive integers. Prove that
$$\frac{(a_1n)!(a_2n)!\cdots (a_Kn)!}{(b_1n)!(b_2n)!\cdots (b_Ln)!} $$
is an integer for all positive integers $n$ if and only if
$$\lfloor a_1x \rfloor + \lfloor a_2x \rfloor+ \cdots + \lfloor a_Kx \rfloor \geq \lfloor b_1x \rfloor + \lfloor b_2x \rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor b_Lx \rfloor$$
holds for all positive real $x$.

One direction is easy - compare canonical powers of a prime $p$ in the numerator and denominator and if the inequality is true, set $x = \frac{n}{p^i}$ and sum through all $i$.

But how to prove that if the inequality is false, then there is a $n$ which is a counterexample? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=\max(a_1,...,a_K,b_1,...,b_L)$, and let $P$ be the set of primes $p$ such that $p > c^2$.

Let $W$ be the set of rational numbers of the form ${\Large{\frac{n}{p}}}$, where $p\in P$, and $n$ is a positive integer with $n < p\sqrt{p}$.

First we show that $W$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Let $r,s$ be positive reals with $r < s$, and let $I=(r,s)$.

To show $I\cap W$ is nonempty, choose $p\in P$ with $p > \max\Bigl({\Large{\frac{1}{s-r}}},s^2\Bigr)$.

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $r < {\Large{\frac{n}{p}}} < s$.

Such a positive integer $n$ exists since from $p > {\Large{\frac{1}{s-r}}}$ we get $s-r > {\Large{\frac{1}{p}}}$,

Thus ${\Large{\frac{n}{p}}}\in I$.

\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
\frac{n}{p} < s
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{n^2}{p^2} < s^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{n^2}{p^2} < p
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
n^2 < p^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
n < p\sqrt{p}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{n}{p}\in W
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus ${\Large{\frac{n}{p}}}\in I\cap W$, so $I\cap W\ne{\large{\varnothing}}$.

Since $r,s$ are arbitrary positive reals with $r < s$, it follows, as claimed, that $W$ is dense in $[0,\infty)$.

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$
f(x)=
\sum_{i=1}^K \lfloor{a_ix}\rfloor
-
\sum_{j=1}^L \lfloor{b_jx}\rfloor
$$

**Claim:**

If $f(x_0) < 0$ for some positive real number $x_0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that the fraction
$$
\frac{(a_1n)!\cdots (a_Kn)!}{(b_1n)!\cdots (b_Ln)!}
$$
is not an integer.

**Proof:**

Note that $f$ is right-constant since each summand is right-constant, hence for some $\epsilon > 0$, we have $f(x)=f(x_0)$ for all $x\in[x_0,x_0+\epsilon]$.

By the density of $W$, there exists $w\in W$ such that $f(w)=f(x_0)$, so $f(w) < 0$.

Write $w={\Large{\frac{n}{p}}}$ where $p\in P$ and $n$ is a positive integer such that $n < p\sqrt{p}$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&
n < p\sqrt{p}
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
n^2 < p^3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
c^2n^2 < p^4
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
cn < p^2
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\left\lfloor{\frac{cn}{p^2}}\right\rfloor=0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\left\lfloor{\frac{a_in}{p^2}}\right\rfloor=0
\;\;\text{and}\;
\left\lfloor{\frac{b_jn}{p^2}}\right\rfloor=0
\;\,\text{for all}\;\,
i.j
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_p(a_in!)
=
\left\lfloor{\frac{a_in}{p}}\right\rfloor
\;\,\text{and}\;\,
v_p(b_jn!)
=
\left\lfloor{\frac{b_jn}{p}}\right\rfloor
\;\text{for all}\;\,
i.j
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
v_p
\left(
\frac{(a_1n)!\cdots (a_Kn)!}{(b_1n)!\cdots (b_Ln)!}
\right)
=
f(w) < 0
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
\frac{(a_1n)!\cdots (a_Kn)!}{(b_1n)!\cdots (b_Ln)!}
\not\in\mathbb{Z}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
as was to be shown.